# How to add dropdownlist into Gridview in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I've a grid control, in that I want to add dropdownlist box. The pupose of the dropdown is to show the page in in the grid, If I select 1 the gridview page1 or 2 means 2nd page in the grid etc, that drop down should not view while I'm going to take print out

My current code:

```
protected void PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    GridViewRow pagerRow = gvDetails.BottomPagerRow; 
    DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList"); 
    gvDetails.PageIndex = pageList.SelectedIndex; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

to add a drop down to a grid cell you should use `ItemTemplates` and especially the edit mode ItemTemplate, see here for a full example: [Walkthrough: Displaying a Drop-Down List While Editing in the GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178294%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

I am anyway not sure about your usage of it, if you need to move from one page to another you should use the Footer/Pager control or you can have a drop down outside the GridView where you select the page then you change the Current PageIndex of the Grid and call DataBind again.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off using Paging - see [Paging in a GridView Web Server Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5aw1xfh3.aspx)

Comment: I think he wants a cell in which he can choose on which page the row should be.

Comment: if i use paging means i want to hide the paging while i m taking print out

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use the `PagerTemplate` as described here: [GridView.PagerTemplate Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate.aspx)

To make your dropdown navigate to a specific page, pass the integer number of that page as the `CommandArgument` on postback.

the example on that page describes how to use a `DropDownList`.

Comment: i have an error in this. when i select 1 & 2 it displays the same record

Comment: I can't really suggest anything else as don't know what your code looks like.

Comment: protected void PageDropDownList_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow pagerRow = gvDetails.BottomPagerRow;
        DropDownList pageList = (DropDownList)pagerRow.Cells[0].FindControl("PageDropDownList");
        gvDetails.PageIndex = pageList.SelectedIndex;
    }
this the drop down i have

Comment: @Rajkumar I've added your code to your question. Did you also add the `GridView_DataBound` event handler to your code, like in the example in my link?

Comment: i have added both GridView_DataBound and dropdown selected index, but it display the first page only

Comment: @Rajkumar All I can advise - unless anyones else has ideas - is to step through the debugger when you change the DropDown value and make sure that it's calling the code as expected and passing the correct page number to the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

Not showing the dropdown on a printed page can be done via a print specific style sheet. This is a reasonable description of what you need to know: http://webdesign.about.com/cs/css/a/aa042103a.htm

The other part, try a customer paging template, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pagertemplate.aspx